# How to delete delay when load a video in WMP

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I'm doing a new game in C# where I need to load some videos.
I'm using Windows Media Player. When I stop "VideoA", I have to load "VideoB" immediately, instead now between VideoA and VideoB there are 0.5 seconds where screen is black.

Follow my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int pressZero = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Console.WriteLine(pressZero);
            Video1.URL = @"C:\Users\utente\Documents\VideoA.avi";
            Video1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
        }
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode==Keys.NumPad0)
            {
                pressZero++;
                if(pressZero==1)
                {
                    Video1.Ctlcontrols.play();
                }
            }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.NumPad2)
            {
                Video1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
                Video1.URL = @"C:\Users\utente\Documents\VideoB.avi";
                Video1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I press NumPad2, VideoA stops and VideoB begin but now there are 0.5 seconds of black screen.

Someone could help me to delete this delay?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It takes lots of time to actually read that file and start playing it. Windows Media Player control is definitely not the fastest one. I suggest creating multiple controls and just changing their visibility. Like:

```
Video1.URL = @"C:\Users\utente\Documents\VideoA.avi";
Video2.URL = @"C:\Users\utente\Documents\VideoB.avi";
```

And then just go like:

```
Video1.Visible = false;
Video2.Visible = true;
```

Comment: you would say that I have to create two AxWindowsMediaPlayer?
When I get start "Video2"?

Comment: Yeah, you just create as many players as you need when the app starts. And then you show/hide them when needed.